# Where can I find a .NET OAuth library that supports OAuth 2.0?

Tags: .net, oauth, security, dotnetopenauth

I need a .NET OAuth Library that can support OAuth version 2.0. Is there one out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OAuth 2 is still a draft. There's a [preview of DotNetOpenAuth](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/CTP/OAuth2/) that supports it.